# gcc link the shared library in specified path but not in the standard path

Tags: c, linux, gcc, linker, shared-libraries

I came across a strange issue when using gcc to link the shared library in specified path but not in the standard path.

When I downloaded [GNU readline library version 6.3](http://cnswww.cns.cwru.edu/php/chet/readline/rltop.html) and compiled it successfully in path **$HOME/Downloads**.

GNU readline library needs to link **libtinfo**, so I installed it by `sudo apt-get install libtinfo`.

After that, I created a small sample test named **rl.c** to check it. To build my sample project, I also created two symbolic links like follow:

```
$ ls -lrt ~/Downloads/
drwxr-xr-x 6 sfzhang sfzhang    4096 Mar  2 15:45 readline-6.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 sfzhang sfzhang      12 Mar  2 16:00 readline -> readline-6.3

$ ls -lrt ~/Downloads/readline-6.3/shlib/
-rwxr-xr-x 1 sfzhang sfzhang 833856 Mar  2 15:36 libreadline.so.6.3
lrwxrwxrwx 1 sfzhang sfzhang     18 Mar  2 16:28 libreadline.so -> libreadline.so.6.3
```

To use the new built readline library, I export the path to **LD_LIBRARY_PATH**:

```
$ echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/sfzhang/Downloads/readline/shlib
```

And, I compiled **rl.c** using the following command:

```
$ gcc -o rl rl.c -I$HOME/Downloads -L$HOME/Downloads/readline/shlib -lreadline -ltinfo
```

Checking the **rl** linked libraries:

```
$ ldd rl
linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fffe09a3000)
libreadline.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6 (0x00007fe22d243000)
libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007fe22d01a000)
libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe22cc8d000)
/lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007fe22d492000)
```

I also tried anther command, but got the same result:

```
gcc -o rl rl.c -I$HOME/Downloads -L$HOME/Downloads/readline/shlib -lreadline -ltinfo -Wl,-rpath,$HOME/Downloads/readline/shlib
```

So, why the **rl** was liked to **/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6** but not **$HOME/Downloads/readline/shlib/libreadline.so**.

OS: Linux debian 3.2.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.2.65-1+deb7u1 x86_64 GNU/Linux

gcc: gcc version 4.7.2 (Debian 4.7.2-5)

ldd: ldd (Debian EGLIBC 2.13-38+deb7u6) 2.13

Comment: ~/Downloads/readline or ~/Downloads/readline-6.3?

Comment: ~/Downloads/readline is the symbolic link to ~/Downloads/readline-6.3

Comment: there is no libreadline.so in readline/shlib: you should do in readline/shlib  ln -s libreadline.so.6.2 libreadline.so

Comment: I also created the symbolic link, see above.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a symbolic link called `libreadline.so.6` too, not just `libreadline.so`. The reason is that the `soname` of `libreadline.so.6.3` is `libreadline.so.6`.

A `soname` is a "generic" name embedded in the library itself. When you link against a shared library that has a `soname`, it is that name that gets embedded in your executable and is later looked up by the dynamic linker. (For shared libraries without `sonames` the filename is used instead, though this is uncommon.) You can tell what the `soname` of a library is by running e.g.

```
objdump -p <library> | grep SONAME
```

The point of `soname`s is to make it so that your executable is linked against the most generic library name that should be compatible (usually this is the library name with just the *major version* -- 6 in this case -- tacked on), rather than just the specific (e.g., minor bug fix release) version that you happened to link against.

The output from `ldd` also tells you that it's looking specifically for `libreadline.so.6`.

Comment: Symbolic links are for `ld` and they are normally unversioned.

Comment: @Maxim Egorushkin How do you mean? It's true that `-lreadline` will use the symbolic link, but the library name that gets embedded in the executable will still come from the library's `soname`, meaning the dynamic linker will look for `libreadline.so.6` and not find it in his directory.

Comment: Read up on http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Program-Library-HOWTO/shared-libraries.html : _there's the name that the compiler uses when requesting a library, (I'll call it the ``linker name''), which is simply the soname without any version number_

Comment: I do not think the `linker name` is relevant at runtime. Try e.g. `gcc test.c /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libreadline.so.6.3` (or wherever your system keeps it) and you'll see (using e.g. `ldd`) that the dynamic linker is simply looking for `libreadline.so.6` (the `soname`). There might be a way to embed an absolute path to a library in an executable, but I can't recall it off the top of my head.

Comment: You are right, an extra link with the major version number is required.

Comment: Thanks @Ulfalizer! I `ln -s libreadline.so.6.3 libreadline.so.6` to solve the issue!

Answer (score 2):

If you really want a path to a library to be hardcoded in the executable, you will need to pass the following to gcc:

`-Wl,-rpath=$HOME/Downloads/readline/shlib`

setting custom LD_LIBRARY_PATH is not recommended, if you want to use it, use it as a parameter for execution.

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$HOME/Downloads/readline/shlib ./rc
```

Comment: That command line builds an executable, not an object file. To build an object file `-c` command line switch is required.

Comment: And I think the right syntax is `-Wl,-rpath,$HOME...`

Comment: I believe on GNU '=' can be used as well.

Answer (score 0):

The are alternative ways to fix your issue:

1. Link against full path to the `.so`. E.g.

   ```
   $ gcc -o rl rl.c -I$HOME/Downloads $HOME/Downloads/readline/shlib/readline.so.6.3 -ltinfo
   ```

   And as @Ulfalizer suggests, you may need another symbolic link with just the major number.
2. If you are using `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` do not forget to export it.
3. When using `-L<path>` also use `-Wl,-rpath,<path>`, so that runtime linker `ld.so.2` finds the shared library in the same path as `ld` does, e.g:

   ```
   $ gcc -o rl rl.c -I$HOME/Downloads -L$HOME/Downloads/readline/shlib -Wl,-rpath,$HOME/Downloads/readline/shlib -lreadline -ltinfo
   ```

When debugging linker issues use `readelf -d <binary>` command to see which exact versions of shared libraries `<binary>` needs (NEEDED attribute) and where it looks for them (RPATH attribute) prior to looking in the standard linker directories (configuration in /etc/ld.so.conf/).